# SQL Server filtered index "Estimated number of rows to be read" is size of full table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-execution-plan

I have a table in an Azure SQL database with ~2 million rows. On this table I have two pairs of columns that I want to filter for null - so I have filtered indexes on each pairs, checking for null on each column.

One of the indexes appears to be about twice the size of the other - (~400,000 vs ~800,000 rows).

However it seems to take about 10x as long to query.

I'm running the exact same query on both:

```
SELECT DomainObjectId 
FROM DomainObjects
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT <id1> AS Id
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT<id2> etc...
    ) AS DomainObjectIds ON DomainObjectIds = DonorIds.Id 
WHERE C_1 IS NULL 
  AND C_2 IS NULL
```

Where C_1/C_2 are the columns with the filtered index (and get replaced with other columns in my other query).

The query plans both involve an Index Seek - but in the fast one, it's 99% of the runtime. In the slow case, it's a mere 50% - with the other half spent *filtering* (which seems suspect, given the filtering should be implicit from the filtered index), and then joining to the queried IDs.

In addition, the "estimated number of rows to be read" for the index seek is ~2 million, i.e. the size of the full table. Based on that, it looks like what I'd expect a full table scan to look like. I've checked the index sizes and the "slow" one only takes up twice the space of the "fast" one, which implies it's not just been badly generated.

I don't understand:

- (a) Why so much time is spent re-applying the filter from the index
- (b) Why the estimated row count is so high for the "slow" index
- (c) What could cause these two queries to be so different in speed, given the similarities in the filtered indexes. I would expect the slow one to be twice as slow, based purely on the number of rows matching each filter.

[image: Fast Index]

[image]

Comment: Please include the table and index DDL and execution plans.

Comment: Upload the actual plans to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the links to your question.